# SQL Invalid operation for DateTime or Interval when casting a hour/minute to an existing Timestamp

Tags: sql, casting, timestamp, teradata, datetime-format

I'm trying to cast an existing Date variable as a timestamp, and add hours and minutes from another Time variable to get a final variable of the format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:00.

The current line of the query that errors out is:

```
  cast(DepDt as timestamp) + cast(substr(ArrTm, 1, 2) as interval hour) + cast(substr(ArrTm, 3, 2) as interval minute) as Arrv_DTML
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong though. I have gotten rid of the substring functions to make sure it wasn't something wrong with that, but I can't seem to cast the ArrTm as an interval even on its own. Is it something with the format of the variables? I am running this in Teradata.

DepDt is a Date. ArrTM is a Time variable.

Comment: Instead of casting, you might want to try the various [time/date conversion functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp).

Comment: I was looking into this...can it be done with existing variables as well? or only hard-coded dates/times?

Comment: try this : select timestamp(curdate());

Comment: @TomDrake: This is Teradata not MySQL.

Comment: I somehow missed that. But [Teradata implements similar date/time functions](https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/functions/datetime.html), with different syntax.

Comment: @TomDrake: No, these are Presto functions. Presto is a SQL Engine for querying heterogeneous data sources (e.g. Hadoop). Teradata functions are based on Standard SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply `substr` on a Time, you must explicitly cast it to a VarChar first:

```
Cast(DepDt AS TIMESTAMP(0))+
+ Cast(Substr(Cast(ArrTm AS VARCHAR(8)), 1, 5) AS INTERVAL HOUR TO  MINUTE)
```

But there's an easier way to get your result:

```
Cast(DepDt AS TIMESTAMP(0))                           -- date to Timestamp
+ (Extract(HOUR From ArrTm) * INTERVAL '1' HOUR)      -- hour to Interval
+ (Extract(MINUTE From ArrTm) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)  -- minute to Interval
```

Comment: this works! thank you so much. Could you explain what the "* Interval '1' Hour/Minute" do for my curiosity?

Comment: Well, EXTRACT returns a number (which can't be added to a timestamp), but when you multiply it times '1' hour/minute it's changed to an INTERVAL (which can be added)